# How do I make a Discord bot that change status with watching status type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, status

```
  const activities_list = [
  "happy holidays!❄️", 
  "happy holidays!",
  "happy holidays!", 
  "happy holidays!⛄"
  ];
```

```
  bot.on('ready', () => {
      setInterval(() => {
          const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1); 
          bot.user.setActivity(activities_list[index]);
      }, 30000); 
    });
```

But i want to display this in WATCHING status type, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by looking at [the Discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity), that gives a direct example for what you're after:

```
client.user.setActivity('YouTube', { type: 'WATCHING' })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
      setInterval(() => {
          const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1); 
          bot.user.setActivity(activities_list[index], {type: 'Watching'});
      }, 30000); 
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.